# box-shadow on Mouse Over issue in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have following css class For IE7

```
    .shadow
            {

                margin-left: -5px;
                margin-top: -5px;
                zoom: 1;
           filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=0),
             progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=90),
             progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=180),
             progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=270)
            }
```

This works greate and generates nice shadow in IE. but i want this effect on Mouse Hover event. so change following css class

```
.shadow
        {
            width:100%;
        }
        .shadow:hover
        {

            margin-left: -5px;
            margin-top: -5px;
            zoom: 1;
       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=0),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=90),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=180),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=270)
        }
```

this doesn't work. Why?? what is the problem in above CSS class?

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .shadow
        {

            width:100%;
        }
        .shadow:hover
        {
            margin-left: -5px;
   margin-top: -5px;
   zoom: 1;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=0),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=90),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=180),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=20, Direction=270)
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="shadow" style="height:100px;width:100px">
        <h1>Swaminarayan</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine in IE8/compatibility mode. I don't have the _real_ IE7 though.

Comment: It should work well in browser except IE6. This is because IE6 only supports the `hover` psuedo for `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a DOCTYPE to make it work in IE7 as it uses a different default DOCTYPE than other browsers. Read more about [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

Just adding the HTML5 DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to the very top of the document is enough and will trigger standards mode in every browser, including IE6.

You can also use an older DOCTYPE like HTML4 Strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

I also had to allow some blocked content using the Internet Explorer Information bar before I could see the shadow effect.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is *the* correct doctype to force standards mode in all browsers, including IE6.

Comment: Ok, I noticed that it did force the standard mode. Great info!